# Using map to connect string with enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I created map that connects enum with strings in order to have easier times doing current project. Code looks like this:

```
struct responseMap : public std::map < std::string, CitizenType > {
    responseMap() {
        this->operator[]("slave") = CitizenType::slave;
        this->operator[]("trader") = CitizenType::trader;
        this->operator[]("priest") = CitizenType::priest;
        this->operator[]("scholar") = CitizenType::scholar;
        this->operator[]("soldier") = CitizenType::soldier;
        this->operator[]("archer") = CitizenType::archer;
        this->operator[]("swordsman") = CitizenType::swordsman;
        this->operator[]("emperor") = CitizenType::emperor;
    }
};
```

My enum is just these types, described in map. Everything works fine exept it doesn't count "slave" as a member of map. For instance if I write down the following code:

```
responseMap myMap;
std::cout<<myMap["slave"]<<" "<<myMap["trader"];
```

it would produce the following line: `0 1`

My question is why this is happening as I am describing them the same way?

Edit: I am trying with normal map like this:

```
std::map<std::string, CitizenType> otherMap = {
    { "slave", CitizenType::slave },
    { "trader", CitizenType::trader },
    { "priest", CitizenType::priest },
    { "scholar", CitizenType::scholar },
    { "soldier", CitizenType::soldier },
    { "archer", CitizenType::archer },
    { "swordsman", CitizenType::swordsman },
    { "emperor", CitizenType::emperor },
};
```

And it still outputs the same values.

Comment: I bet the numeric value of `CitizenType::slave` is 0, and the numeric value of `CitizenType::trader` is 1. Which is what you see printed. What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: You can do (*this)["slave"]= instead of this->operator[]("slave")=

Comment: Very happy to see the civilization of society since slaves are also considered citizens now.

Comment: @texasbruce Only [three fifths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-Fifths_Compromise) of a citizen.

Comment: Ok, I think I have mistaken what I need to do. Basically I have to chech whether `CitizenType::[insert word here]` is a member of the current enum

Answer (score 3):

If you don't set it differently, `enum` will index from 0 - so it isn't ignoring your value, your value is 0. You may want to look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), especially the part about "If the first enumerator does not have an initializer, the associated value is zero. For any other enumerator whose definition does not have an initializer, the associated value is the value of the previous enumerator plus one."

Comment: Yea, I found what I have mistaken. Thanks for the response. So I'm trying to figure out a nice way to chech whether `CitizenType::[insert word here]` is a member of the current enum

Comment: Basic idea will be to check if the index of your string belongs to the range of enum: you need to save the number of elements in enum (because you can't check the highest value) and then check if `myMap[myString] >= 0 and myMap[myString] < numberOfElems`

Comment: I kinda did the same thing but with some difference. Set the start to be equal to 1 and just did the following `if(myMap[word])` so it will return 0 when it doesn't exist and 1 or so when exists.

Comment: Sure, that's a nice solution, if you are doing the indexing from 1. My idea was for the case you leave it from 0.